# Give Azure Build Agent Write Permission to VM Folder

Tags: azure, permissions, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008, symstore

I have two azure entities I'm trying to connect, a build agent running my nuget deployments and a VM (Windows Server 2012 R2) on which I'm trying to set up symbol hosting using SymStore.

From [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/index-sources-publish-symbols) I am told to `Grant full control permission to the build agent service account.` How do I go about doing this? In the `Publish Symbols` build step, I can enter a URL to store the symbols, but I have no way of logging the build agent into the VM as the user that I've given full control permission to.

Answer (score 0):

This setup is actually not possible; from the SymSrv [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681416(v=vs.85).aspx): `writes to an http-based symbol store are not possible`.

It appears that the SymStore has to be on the same machine as the Azure build agent to give it full control permission. I happened to discover that NuGet will let me publish .pdbs, so I'm going to try that route instead.